# MDT deployment adds windows boot manager to boot list after each run

Tags: windows-10, boot, mdt

I'm not sure if this is a problem or just an inconvenience. On a Lenovo T430s, when I PXE boot to install windows using MDT, I first have the options for HDD, DVD, and LAN. After the first installation, if I go back in, I have an additional option: Windows boot manager. While reimaging the same laptop, I have noticed that I get another listing for Windows boot manager each time.

I noticed while making a VM and reimaging it rather than rolling back to a previous version that it ALSO gets more .efi files to choose to boot from after each subsequent image.

1. Do I need to clear these off?
2. Regardless of that answer, how would I get rid of them?
3. And, is there a way to ensure that I don't get multiple boot manager
   files in the future?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answers myself, so to help others who might run across this issue:

1. Not really. Most users will not look at a boot menu.
2. In CMD

   ```
   bcdedit /export bcd
   bcdedit /enum firmware > bcdlist.txt
   ```

   Find the items in a list. In PS

   ```
   $b = @("{whatever},{whateverelse},...")
   foreach ($a in $b) {bcdedit /store bcd /delete $a}
   ```

   In CMD

   ```
   bcdedit /import bcd /clean
   ```
3. No.